# Application running out of memory due to apache kafka metric objects while using kafkaProducer

Tags: apache-kafka, garbage-collection, jmx, kafka-producer-api

We try to send 1000s of messages to a kafka-topic using kafkaProducer(`org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`) objects on our tomcat application. Lately we have been observing an issue with large number of kafkaMetric objects being created on the heap.

We maintain the practise of closing kafkaProducer objects are a message is sent successfully. Also verified in our threaddumps, thats kafkaProducer objects are not hanging around.

But strangely JmxMBeanServer objects were present in heap space even after many days(as in they were not garbage collected too). Further these JmxMBeanServer objects consisted of metrics objects for kafka-producers present in a hashmap.

The hashmap keys strings were of the format key  java.lang.String `client-id=producer-322,type=producer-metrics`

These hashmap objects were huge in number(more than 1000s).

Why were these metric objects not garbage-collected, even though the kafkaProducer's objects were closed or shutdown.

Is there a way to stop auto creation of these metric objects.

PS:
kafka-clients jar version: `2.8.2`

We tried several closing kafka producer objects at each send message operation, hoping metric objects would also be closed or garbage collected in few minutes. But they hogged up the heap.

Comment: The producer is thread safe. Don't close it (and keep recreating). Make it an application singleton, such as using logback / log4j2 Kafka logger. Sounds like that would solve much of your problem...

Comment: @OneCricketeer appreciate your suggestion. However, we dont connect to a single kafka-cluster. We are connecting to mutiple varied kafka-clusters, for different reasons and needs in our huge application, catering to various communication needs. Since we work with different customers, we donot want to share objects among them.

Comment: @OneCricketeer The whole point of raising this post was to identify or figure a way to know and control so many jmxBean objects. Does apache-kafka have any flag which could be placed in ProducerConfig or any other hook method, through which jmxReporter(implementation of MetricReporter) can be stopped, since it creates lots of jmxBeans.

Comment: My comment was referring to your second point of closing after a message is sent. You can make one Producer per cluster / client, whatever. You just don't need to always be closing those each time you send one batch of events. You could set some other TTL on producer objects in a threadpool if you really wanted to garbage collect many instances... I am not familiar with the internals of the JMXReporter class. But the ProducerConfig is all listed in the documentation, as is the JavaDoc for the Producer class, and I haven't seen anything related to this. You could also try upgrading to 3.x

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Seems like a alternative approach to have unique producer.                             
 But the question still remains, how do we handle closing or stop unneccessary creation of jmx metric objects. Is there a way provided from apache-kafka side. Or is there an existing example of the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything like that, that wouldn't involve using reflection to remove the internal JMX registry. I suggest mailing the Kafka developers list for any suggestions as they'd know more. Otherwise search JIRA for similar issues

Comment: If you really want to remove JVM heap usage, perhaps you write your code in a different language like Go or Rust that are more memory efficient

Comment: I hope, we had any suggestion or pointers from apache kafka code-owners for above query.